# Add ng-class when Click event triggered in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

i create simple application. And i add rating feature.
I want to change the rating star class when click event is triggered from controller.

In my Controller i check if the rating of object == passed number from view, i return class name `active`.

After that, i still confused how i pass my return value.

Here is my **View**

```
<h3>{{ fruit.title }}</h3>
                <div class="rating">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-click="addRating(1,fruit)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i></li>
                        <li ng-click="addRating(2,fruit)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i></li>
                        <li ng-click="addRating(3,fruit)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i></li>
                        <li ng-click="addRating(4,fruit)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i></li>
                        <li ng-click="addRating(5,fruit)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

And here is my **Controller** :

```
var app = angular.module('totalBuahApp', []);

app.controller('fruitController', function($scope) {
    $scope.fruits = [
        {
            title : 'Fresh Red Apple',
            img : 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/512/Apple.png',
            description : 'Good for your daily consumption.',
            price : 15000,
            cartQty : 1,
            rating : 0
        },
        {
            title : 'Red Grape',
            img : 'http://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/grape/4-grape-png-image-download-picture-thumb.png',
            description : 'Like a king.',
            price : 34000,
            cartQty : 1,
            rating : 0
        }
    ];

    $scope.total = $scope.fruits.length;

    $scope.addRating = function(number, fruit) {
        fruit.rating = number;
    };

    $scope.ratingClass = function(number) {
        return (number == $scope.rating) ? "active" : "";   
    };
});
```

You can check my fullcode in 
https://codepen.io/fanjavaid/pen/MaRWgG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't duplicate HTML for every star, use ngRepeat with ngClass:

```
<div class="rating">
    <ul>
        <li class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"
            ng-click="addRating($index + 1, fruit)"
            ng-repeat="star in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]"
            ng-class="{active: fruit.rating >= $index + 1}"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWOPad?editors=101

Comment: :D yes, thank you for your advice. But i still don't understand in this line `{active: fruit.rating >= $index + 1}`. Please explain that line to me ^^.

Comment: This is usual [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) syntax. Means, set class "active" when `fruit.rating >= $index + 1` condition is met. `$index` is what `ngRepeat` sets on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your rating Div with the below div

```
    <div class="rating">
       <ul>
           <li ng-click="addRating(1,fruit)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" ng-class="{active:fruit.rating >= 1}"></i></li>
           <li ng-click="addRating(2,fruit)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" ng-class="{active:fruit.rating >= 2}"></i></li>
           <li ng-click="addRating(3,fruit)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" ng-class="{active:fruit.rating >= 3}"></i></li>
           <li ng-click="addRating(4,fruit)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" ng-class="{active:fruit.rating >= 4}"></i></li>
           <li ng-click="addRating(5,fruit)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" ng-class="{active:fruit.rating >= 5}"></i></li>
     </ul>
```

and add .active class in your css.